# I want to add css for my child class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I add CSS to my child of child element, i tried this code

```
.inactive-property {
    background-color: #e85050;
    color: white!important;
}

.inactive-property > .mng-prop-span{
    color: white!important;
}
```

My DOM element like

```
<div class="inactive-property">
    <div class="a">
        <div class="aa">
            <div class="mng-prop-span"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

I want to apply css on class `mng-prop-span`

Comment: .inactive-property  .mng-prop-span

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element that is a member of the `mng-prop-span` class is not a **child** of the element that is a member of the `inactive-property`. It is a **great-grandchild**.

Use a [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) (a space: ) and not a [child combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) (`>`).

Comment: @Jimbrooism — The question doesn't need editing. It is perfectly understandable and possible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    .inactive-property > .mng-prop-span{
    color: white!important;
}
```

The first line is not correct. `>` is used for a quick next child. Better you try it without `>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply like that

```
.inactive-property .mng-prop-span{
    color: white;
}
```

It will match the `.mng-prop-span` class inside `.inacvite-property` class
You do not have to use important property here.

If you want to match `only` those elements that are `child of "aa" element inside "inactive-property"` you can do this like that

```
.inactive-property .aa > .mng-prop-span{
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pe73r8bt/)**

code :

```
.inactive-property {
background-color: #e85050;
color: white;
height:100px;
width:100px;
}

.inactive-property  .mng-prop-span{
color: black;
}
```

1. `.mng-prop-span` it's not a direct child of the `.inactive-property` , but it's a descendant so instead of `>` use `.inactive-property  .mng-prop-span{` with a simple space between the two

2.`>` is a child selector that selects children that are **directly** under the parent

3. i suggest you don't use `!important` only when it's absolutely necessary
4. for more info click here **[CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)**

EDIT : could you explain the downvote ? ( the one who downvoted ) . i am very curious